# YII CRUD outputs blank page

Tags: yii, crud, gii

I just created a new project with YII framework, connected it to database (on localhost, xampp), created model using GII module. After that I used gii CRUD tool to create controllers and views.
GII creates everything successfully, but when I click the button "Try it now", it redirects me to blank page.

I tried to enter the link manually:

```
    http://localhost/StorageSite/index.php?r=recenice/index
```

but I get the same output - blank white page.

Comment: post some error logs . .

Comment: This type of question has been posted a gazzlion-framillion times. Please tell us what you tried, and please, please tell us that this included hitting the search button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings